# Project with Native Code required?

Tags: react-native

I'm reading some docs and it is stated explicitly that 'Project with Native Code Required'. I'm also poking around several apps on Github, but is there a way to check if it was created using `react-native init` or is native code? What does 'project with native code' actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

Native code === ios and android projects.

So projects with the native projects in them (called android and ios)

Comment: Right. So projects with `android` and `ios` subdirectories are 'projects with native code'?

Answer (score 0):

Native code is the code that you see after you have ejected your app which will then create folder `android` and `ios` folder. Thats native code.

If you look inside `android` folder you will see that there is Java/Android code which is used to build into production. Same goes for `ios` directory.